# Firefox addon SDK Tabs Access

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am following an example from [Mozilla Docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html)

```
tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  tab.attach({
    contentScript: 'self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);',
    onMessage: function (message) {
      console.log(message);
    }
  });
});
```

with a little modification like this.

```
var bodyHTML;
tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
  tab.attach({
    contentScript: 'self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML);',
    onMessage: function (message) {
      bodyHTML = message;
      console.log("From attach : "  + bodyHTML);
    }
  });
});
console.log("After tab : " + bodyHTML);
```

Now when I execute this addon, `console.log("After tab : " + bodyHTML);` is getting executed first and then `console.log("From attach : "  + bodyHTML);`. What could be the issue and how can I order the sequence of execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tabs.on()` call sets up an event.  It doesn't directly cause anything else to happen.  The function in the `onMessage` property is triggered by the message which is posted by the content script, which itself is triggered by the activation of a tab (typically the visiting of a web page).  The `console.log()` is executed right after the `tabs.on()` call just above it, most likely before any tabs are attached.